# MySQL error when trying to insert datetime

Tags: c#, mysql, datetime

APPEARS LIKE THE ISSUE WAS NOT DATETIME AFTERALL!

EDIT:

```
MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand();
cmd.CommandText = 
    String.Format("INSERT INTO matches VALUES ({0}, {1}, {2}), {3}, {4}, {5}, {6}", 
        matchid, status, team1, team2, fixteam1logo, fixteam2logo, matchtime);
cmd.Connection = conn;
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: What error do you get? It works fine for me when I place `SELECT` in front of it on the command line.

Comment: Oops it may appear that my issue is not connected to the datetime but rather something else, Do you know what could be causing the following issue 


MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: 'You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'G2, 5310, 5995, 2017-05-08 15:35:00' at line 1'

Comment: String values (and date/time values) must be quoted. Show your actual code.

Comment: how can i format the code to look better it's so hard to read for you in this comment section

Comment: You can edit your question and put it there.

Comment: oh well I tried. Edited now

Comment: That is not PHP. What language are you using?

Comment: oh I must have mistakenly added PHP in the tags >.< It is C#

Comment: You can apparently use parameters to insert, which bypasses quoting issues. I found a tutorial at http://zetcode.com/db/mysqlcsharptutorial/ .

Comment: Thank you I will check it out :)

Answer (score 0):

If it's a date column or datetime column, just pass the value as a string:

```
somedate='2017-05-08 19:19:23' // for a datetime column
somedate='2017-05-08' // for a date column
```